# Cisco 878 Router MPLS WAN Configuration

Tags: cisco, router, mpls

I'm a network-naive telecom guy. I have a Cisco 878 router.
My duty is to set up some configuration on it with the following parameters:

```
MPLS Settings:
LAN IP: 123.123.123.123 / 1
WAN IP: 456.456.456.456 / 2
VPI: 42
VCI: 95
Speed: 2048
No VLAN (access ports)
```

Now, I have managed to connect the router to my laptop via the console cable, and used a HyperTerminal to connect to the device.
I need to mention that the router is already configured for some other (ATM?) connection. We need to get rid of that and re-configure it for our new connection.
I have gone through numerous manuals and helps online, but they seem to be not working for me.
For example, my command line starts with:

```
    Refinery>_
```

and when I press `?` I can't find `Router` listed in there. But all the manuals and forums are talking about `Router (Config...)`. 
Would you guide me to this?
Thanks in advance
-Amin

Comment: This is all very basic stuff, and we can't give you a complete course on how to configure routers. You need to get into `enable` mode, then you can `configure terminal` to get into configuration mode. I don't have much confidence that you will be able to correctly configure a router if you don't know that much.

Comment: I know dear Run! It's basic. Is there any manual to help quickly on getting this task done? I have a good grasp of programming and I have started reading Network Plus' book already.

Comment: Cisco has entire web sites of documentation. Resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, and we can't give you a course in routing.

Comment: As pointed out by Ron, this question is way too broad and considered basic knowledge.

Comment: Thanks dear Teun! Cisco is unquestionably a huge source of general documents, but this, as my view, is not contradicting sharing a simple guide on configuring MPLS networks for Cisco routers which answers my whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not joking :)

You have to have "enable" password for this router. If you have it, do the following :

Refinery>enable

Password:

Refinery#configure terminal

Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.

Refinery(config)#no hostname

Router(config)#end

Router#

%SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console

Router#disable

Router>

Comment: Thanks dear Muti! I don't know if I sound joking to you, but be sure it's a real question. Thanks for mentioning password. I'm not sure if there's any, so, I need to give it a try. BTW, can you help where it says: Enter configuration commands, one per line? For example setting LAN,WAN ip and VPI/VCI? Thanks again! :)

Comment: @AminVanda, if you need that type of help, you need to hire someone to set this up for you. You are asking about many different and varied protocols, and you don't even have the knowledge to begin to understand or assist. The scope of this question is huge, and this site is not designed for that. That's why there isn't a simple guide for setting up MPLS; you need basic _and_ advanced knowledge of routing in general, and BGP and whichever IGPs you are using in particular, and that's before you can even start to understand MPLS. You want years worth of study and experience handed to you.

Comment: I think, you should ask the right question to get a meaningful answer. At this point the right question would be: how can I configure Cisco router if I do not know it's password. You google it and get a ton of answers and videos, here is one of those: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/800-series-routers/12065-pswdrec-827.html  And when you get into (config) mode, you look around and learn things.

Comment: I get it. I need to break it down. Like step-by-step problems I encounter in the path of configuration. However, I found a solution to this. Since there are many things to know about this configuration, I just had to edit IP's and VPI and PCI of the current config. So, All I did was show running-configuration, and then Found where these parameters were set and just set again with the new parameters. See? I don't have to master the whole network engineering to make this done.

Comment: So you managed to get inside, great.  Didn't think telecom functions that way, but again - the result matters :))

Comment: Yup. It works fine, although I don't really know what I've done. Hey, don't underestimate telecom guys! ;)